# Linker cannot find implementation in include directory

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm using `gcc` on `WSL` to compile a `C++` `Linux` project. I wanted to use the [`base64` encode/decode](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64) library so I installed it with [`vcpkg`](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). I'm including the library's functions via `#include <cpp-base64/base64.h>`. However, this causes a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `base64_encode[abi:cxx11](unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
```

Upon investigating the `include` directory, I see nothing unusual:

```
/bin/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/cpp-base64$ ls
base64.cpp  base64.h
```

As a test I decided to copy the `base64.cpp` into my source code directory directly and it linked correctly. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the linker pick up the `base64.cpp` implementation from the `include` directory without any problems?

Comment: No, it won't pick it up automatically. The include directory will only look for things you `#include` in your project. I don't know how the library manager works, but you have to pass the library's `.lib` or `.obj` file to the linker. Or you could include the `.cpp` file, but that might cause problems in certain situations and is generally not recommended.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: There is no `.lib` or `.obj` file, it should simply use the source code. Including the `.cpp` file instead of the `.h` file also works. I still think that this is strange behavior. Usually it works by including the header file.

Comment: You can pass the `.cpp` file to `gcc` and it'll create an `.obj` file and link it with your program. How are you building the program? When has it worked by just including the header? This is how it should work, but if you're using a build system and IDE it might have done it automatically for you.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: I'm using `CMake` and `CLion`/`Visual Studio` with it. Including the header usually works since it finds the implementation with the same file name in the same directory.

Comment: Are you sure about that? When I'm using CMake I always have to add the source file to the project, either directly to the target or as a library. However, my IDE (Clion) adds these automatically by modifying the CMakeLists.txt when it notices a new source file. Maybe you could include your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman: The `CMakeLists.txt` file does not mention those library includes since they are outside of the project. The package manager `vcpkg` supplies all libraries to the system's default include directory so `CMake` can "see" them.